# Stylecop rules gets ignored in the IDE?

Tags: c#, roslyn, jetbrains-ide, rider, stylecop

I have a Stylecop ruleset that looks like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="CustomRules" Description="Custom StyleCop Ruleset" ToolsVersion="16.0">
  <!-- General Settings -->
  <Rules AnalyzerId="StyleCop.Analyzers" RuleNamespace="StyleCop.Analyzers">

    <!-- SA1001: Symbols should be prefixed by space -->
    <Rule Id="SA1001" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1003: The spacing around an operator symbol is incorrect -->
    <Rule Id="SA1003" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1012: Opening curly brackets should be spaced correctly -->
    <Rule Id="SA1012" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1013: Closing curly brackets should be spaced correctly -->
    <Rule Id="SA1013" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1025: Code should not contain multiple whitespace in a row -->
    <Rule Id="SA1025" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1028: Code must not contain trailing whitespace -->
    <Rule Id="SA1028" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1116: Split parameters should start on line after declaration -->
    <Rule Id="SA1116" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1122: Use string interpolation instead of concatenation -->
    <Rule Id="SA1122" Action="Error" />
    
    <!-- SA1503: Braces should not be omitted -->
    <Rule Id="SA1503" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1507: Code must not contain multiple blank lines in a row -->
    <Rule Id="SA1507" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1513: Closing brace should be followed by blank line -->
    <Rule Id="SA1513" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1515: Single-line comment must be preceded by blank line -->
    <Rule Id="SA1515" Action="Error" />

    <!-- SA1516: Adjacent C# elements must be separated by a blank line. -->
    <Rule Id="SA1516" Action="Error" />

    <!-- S1481: Unused local should be removed -->
    <Rule Id="S1481" Action="Warning" />

    <!-- S4487: Duplicate local variable -->
    <Rule Id="S4487" Action="Warning" />
    
    <!-- SA1202: Elements should be ordered by access -->
    <Rule Id="SA1202" Action="Warning" />

    <!-- Ignore all other rules -->
    <Rule Id="*" Action="None" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

As you can see everything that's not specified isn't considered as "issues", however in Rider you can see that I have some warnings even though that shouldn't happen given the above file :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated !